# Test whether the function $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}$ is contraction or NOT

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> Let , $X=\{x\in \Bbb R: x\ge 1\}$. Define a map $f:X\to X$ by $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\in X$. Examine if $f$ is contraction map or not w.r.t. usual metric on $\Bbb R$. Find the smallest $\lambda$, as contraction constant.

We have $|f(x)-f(y)|=\left |\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{xy}\right)(x-y)\right |\le |x-y|.\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{|xy|}\right)\le \frac{3}{2}|x-y|$

From here how I can say that $f$ is a contraction map ?

As, $x,y\ge 1$ so , $1/xy \le 1$. If we take $x,y\in X$ such that $1/xy=1/4$ then the constant $\lambda=1/2+1/4=3/4<1$. But $f$ to be contraction we have to show for all $x,y\in X$ , $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \lambda|x-y|$. So why I will take $x,y$ such that $1/xy=1/4$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave up too much when you used the triangle inequality to get
$$\left|\frac12 -\frac{1}{xy}\right| \le \left(\frac12 + \frac{1}{xy}\right).$$

Since $x,y\ge 1, 0 < \displaystyle \frac{1}{xy}\le 1$, as you said. So the greatest distance $\displaystyle \frac{1}{xy}$ can have from $\displaystyle \frac12$ is $\displaystyle \frac12$.

Now you have a contraction. Before, with Lipschitz constant $\displaystyle \frac32$, you did not have a contraction.

Comment: I got it. In that case the smallest value of $\lambda$ is $0$. Am I right?

Comment: If $\lambda=0$ held, $f$ would be constant. Is $f$ constant?

Comment: Ok..But $1/xy$ may be $1/2$. Then $\lambda=0$.
How I can calculate the smallest value of $\lambda$ ?

Comment: The point is you want a contraction constant that holds for $\textit{all}$ $x,y$. Not just for those that satisfy $xy=2$. You know that $\displaystyle \frac12$ works. Try to show that it is the $\textit{best}$ constant you can get by showing that there are $x,y$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| = \displaystyle \frac12 |x-y|$.

Comment: Yeah. Then I've to show only $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$. But I'm unable to show it. In that case I'm trying to show $|1/2-1/xy|\ge 1/2$. But I am not getting any logic for it !

Comment: Okay. Here's what I'm saying. You've shown that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le \displaystyle\frac12 |x-y|$ for all $x,y$ in your domain. Now I want you to show that you $\textit{cannot}$ improve that constant out front. Show that for some $x,y$, you have equality $|f(x) - f(y)| = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$. If you do, you will be done. Because that means you can't say $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \alpha |x-y|$ for all $x,y$ for any $\alpha < \displaystyle \frac12$. This last bit should be easy. There are some easy guesses for where equality should hold.

Comment: Oh you know what, the points I had in mind for equality were actually things like $x=2, y= 1/2$. I forgot that that wouldn't be allowed. Still, $1/2$ should be the best you can do. Hold $x=1$ fixed and send $y \to \infty$ and it should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The estimate
$$\Big|\frac12 - \frac1{xy}\Big| \le \frac12 + \frac1{xy}$$
is too bad. Try to find a better estimate. (What are the possible values for $xy$?)

Comment: Well. $1/xy \le 1$  always. Then , $|1/2-1/xy|\le 1/2$. Is it ?

Comment: (And $1/xy \ge 0$). Yes, I think $1/2$ is the best possible constant.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)
=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}
$
so
$f'(x)
=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x^2}
\le \frac12
$
for
$x \ge 1$/

Therefor,
by the mean value theorem,
$f(x)-f(y)
=(x-y)f'(z)
$
where
$x \le z \le y$
so that
$|f(x)-f(y)|
\le\frac12|x-y|
$.

If 
$M
\lt x < y$,
then,
if
$x \le z \le y$,
$f'(z)
\gt \frac12-\frac1{M^2}
$
so that
$|f(x)-f(y)|
=|x-y||f'(z)|
\gt (\frac12-\frac1{M^2})|x-y|
$
so that
$\frac12$
is the best possible value.

Comment: From the last line of your answer how I can say that $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$ ? I'm not getting the logic behind it.

Comment: It says that, for any $c > 0$, there is an $M$ such that $M < x < y$ implies that $|f(x)-f(x)| > (\frac12-c)|x-y|$, so that no constant smaller than $1/2$ will work for all $x$ and $y$.